# How to avoid for loop in Matlab when building a new matrix from a database

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with two columns with about 500 rows. The values of first column vary from 1 to 48. This means that there are repeating numbers in the first column. 
I need to make to build a new matrix with 48 rows that each row includes information for a specific number in column 1. For example consider the following data:

```
x = [ 3 500
5 400
3 200
1 100
1 1100 
2 450 
3 890
1 110
2 800
....]
```

So, the out put matrix should be:

```
Output = [100 1100 110 ...0 0 0; 450 800 ... 0 0 0; 8200 890 0 0 0 ...; 0 0 0];
```

I know how to do it using for loop but I need to do it without a for loop.

I used the following lines

```
XX = X(:,2);

Output = XX(X(:,1)==(1:48)');
```

But it did no work because the number of rows in the new matrix is not the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the sub2ind function, I recommend reading the documentation to understand how this works. We'll place all the x(:,2) values into a matrix M. The row that each value belongs in depends on the x(:,1) values, so we must determine which column the value belongs to.

Below j is calculated such that j(k) is equal to the number of times x(k,1) occurs in the vector x(1:k,1). This will be the column we want to place the value x(k,2) into.

```
x = [ 3 500
5 400
3 200
1 100
1 1100 
2 450 
3 890
1 110
2 800];

j = sum(triu(x(:,1)==x(:,1)'));     % Calculate the column each value should be placed into
M = zeros(max(x(:,1)), max(j));   % Set up the empty matrix
ind = sub2ind(size(M), x(:,1), j(:)); % Get linear indices from subscripts
M(ind) = x(:,2)

M =

     100        1100         110
     450         800           0
     500         200         890
       0           0           0
     400           0           0
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.